# Sending files over serial port

Tags: c, linux, file, serial-port

I need some help sending a file over a serial connection. I have two RS232 to USB cables, and I am testing out my code by using one to send data, and the other to receive it. I have them both physically connected to each other.

So I wrote some code adapted from a few sources, and I can successfully transfer a series of characters. One program receives the data, the other sends it. I have these two open in two separate terminals. Find the two blocks of code below:

**serialout.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

int main()
    {
            //writing
            int writeport = open_port("/dev/ttyUSB0");

            char str[] = "hello how are you?";
            int n = write(writeport, str, strlen(str));
            if (n < 0)
                    fputs("write() of bytes failed!\n", stderr);

            //closing ports
            close(writeport);
    }

    int open_port(char str[])
{
    int fd = open(str, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK); // ?? NDELAY or NONBLOCK?

  if (fd == -1)
  {
                    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
  }
  else
                    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

      struct termios options;
      tcgetattr(fd, &options); //this gets the current options set for the port

      // setting the options

      cfsetispeed(&options, B9600); //input baudrate
      cfsetospeed(&options, B9600); // output baudrate
      options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); // ?? enable receicer and set local mode
      //options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* mask the character size bits */
      options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* select 8 data bits */
      options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // choosing raw input
      options.c_iflag &= ~INPCK; // disable parity check
      options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // disable software flow control
      options.c_oflag |= OPOST; // ?? choosing processed output
      options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; // Wait until x bytes read (blocks!)
      options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; // Wait x * 0.1s for input (unblocks!)

      // settings for no parity bit
      options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
      options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
      options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
      options.c_cflag |= CS8;

      tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options); //set the new options ... TCSANOW specifies all option changes to occur immediately

  return (fd);
}
```

**serialin.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

int main()
{
    //reading   
    int readport = open_port("/dev/ttyUSB1");

    //trying to read one character at a time
    char buff;
    int n = 1;

   while (n > 0)
   {
    n = read(readport, &buff, 1);
    printf("%c", buff, buff);
   }

    printf("\n");

    //closing ports
    close(readport);
}

int open_port(char str[])
{
    int fd = open(str, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK); // ?? NDELAY or NONBLOCK?

  if (fd == -1)
  {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
  }
  else
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

  struct termios options;
  tcgetattr(fd, &options); //this gets the current options set for the port

  // setting the options

  cfsetispeed(&options, B9600); //input baudrate
  cfsetospeed(&options, B9600); // output baudrate
  options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); // ?? enable receicer and set local mode
  //options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* mask the character size bits */
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* select 8 data bits */
  options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // choosing raw input
  options.c_iflag &= ~INPCK; // disable parity check
  options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // disable software flow control
  options.c_oflag |= OPOST; // ?? choosing processed output
  options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; // Wait until x bytes read (blocks!)
  options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; // Wait x * 0.1s for input (unblocks!)

  // settings for no parity bit
  options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;

  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options); //set the new options ... TCSANOW specifies all option changes to occur immediately

  return (fd);
}
```

So what I'd like to do is send a file. For example, a jpeg file. Is there some way to convert it to bytecode and reassemble it as a jpeg? I have searched around but have found little relevant information unfortunately - maybe I'm searching the wrong terms.

Even better would be to send the files after they are zipped. Ultimately, I am using gzip to zip jpeg files, then send them over the serial connection. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What's the problem with the method you've come up with? Just make a bit bigger buffer.

Comment: Well, how does that work? In the write function, I thought I could only put strings in? And if I were to put a file in, what would I enter for the number of bytes being sent? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why dis you think you can only supply a string to write? And simply put the file size as size.

Comment: So do you mean, I could just write write(writeport, "/home/sendtest", 25)? I have populated sendtest with 25 bytes of information. It still isn't working, perhaps I am doing something wrong by writing the file name in quotations? Thanks.

Comment: OMG. You need to READ the DATA outta FILE and supply that buffer to write.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really a beginner with this stuff. But thanks for your help and patience. I'll try what you suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to transfer files, you should break the file up into chunks, and use a checksum on each chunk; then verify the checksums as you rejoin the chunks on the other side.

This is not a new problem.  Others have solved it for you.  You should get an existing reliable file-transfer program and run it over the serial link.

The top choice would be rsync.  That is GPL, so the license may keep you from using it if you are doing proprietary work.

Another good choice would be XMODEM (or YMODEM or ZMODEM).  I found a C implementation of XMODEM with a BSD license, so you can use this for sure.  This is also smaller and simpler than rsync.

http://www.menie.org/georges/embedded/#xmodem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM

Comment: Cool response! I'll look into those as well, but I would love to get my current code working too. I think I am quite close, and will implement the checksum. Also, I do split up the jpeg file using the imagemagick utility into smaller parts. I gzip those parts. Then I want to send the zipped pieces, unzip them on the other side, and recombine them to form the original image. Thanks.

Comment: If your serial connection is really reliable and noise-free, then you may not need the checksum feature.  But serial ports are so simple that a little bit of electrical noise can introduce bit errors, so the checksums are a good idea, and since the code is already written and already out there you might as well just use it.  One warning with XMODEM: I think it rounds up file sizes.  You could fix that with some extra code, or maybe you could find ZMODEM code.

Comment: If you are already planning to use gzip or tar on the files before you send them, then there might not be any problem with XMODEM rounding up the file size.  The archive file might get rounded up but then when you unpack the archive and get the original files out, they will all be the correct size.

Comment: Since you set the serial port to 8-bit mode, you can send 8-bit data bytes without them getting mangled, so it should be possible for you to just open a serial port for reading, open a file for writing, and copy bytes from the serial port to the file.  You could make a trivial protocol where you send a special sequence, then the name of the file and its length, and then the binary data bytes.  Your receive code would use the filename to know what name to use when writing the file, and would use the length to know how many bytes to copy.

Comment: Ah I see. Okay, I'll play around with it a little more using your suggestions. Thanks, I'll let you know if I get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

I was also going to suggest Z-Modem or X-Modem for file transferring. But what you've got to understand is that there's nothing special about files. As far as the transferring computer and receiving terminal are concerned, the file being sent is just a stream of binary data, no matter if it's a jpeg image, a compressed file or just a text file.

All you've got to do is write the incoming stream into a file an make sure it has the right extension so it can be properly handled.

The transfer protocols mentioned above only add layers to ensure the whole file is being sent and that it is not corrupted, but you can dismiss them on a first instance to understand the concept.